# Spring Boot multiple Datasources LazyLoadingException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot Application (v1.4.3) and my objects are serialized with the default Jackson Object Mapper like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "diagnosis", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object diagnosis(Filter filter, Pageable pageable) {

    if (filter) {
        return eventRepository.findAll(filter.toSpecification(), pageable)
    }

    return eventRepository.findAll(pageable)

}
```

If I define only one datasource (application.yml 'spring.datasource...', autoconfigured from spring) everything is working.

Now I need to configure two datasources. For each datasource I have written a config class.

UserDatasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xxx.repository.user", entityManagerFactoryRef = "userEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")
class DatasourceConfigurationUser {

    @Autowired
    private DatasourceSettingsUser datasourceSettingsUser

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "userDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource()
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(datasourceSettingsUser.driverClassName)
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceSettingsUser.url)
        dataSource.setUsername(datasourceSettingsUser.username)
        dataSource.setPassword(datasourceSettingsUser.password)
        return dataSource
    }

    /*
     * Entity Manager Factory setup.
     */

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "userEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource())
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(["xxx.model.user"] as String[])
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(datasourceSettingsUser.toHibernateProperties())
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter())
        return factoryBean
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "userTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager()
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf)
        return txManager
    }

}
```

DataDatasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xxx.repository.data", entityManagerFactoryRef = "dataEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "dataTransactionManager")
class DatasourceConfigurationData {

    @Autowired
    private DatasourceSettingsData datasourceSettingsData

    @Bean(name = "dataDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource()
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(datasourceSettingsData.driverClassName)
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceSettingsData.url)
        dataSource.setUsername(datasourceSettingsData.username)
        dataSource.setPassword(datasourceSettingsData.password)
        return dataSource
    }

    /*
     * Entity Manager Factory setup.
     */

    @Bean(name = "dataEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource())
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(["xxx.model.data"] as String[])
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(datasourceSettingsData.toHibernateProperties())
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter())
        return factoryBean
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager()
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf)
        return txManager
    }

}
```

Now I get nasty LazyLoadingExceptions because Lazy Collections can not be fetched during the Jackson Mapper serialization. I wonder why this is working with the default Spring Boot Datasource!!

Is there anything I have missed during the datasource configuration?

---

Edit 1

This is working in a service layer.

```
@Service
@Transactional
class EventService {

    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository

    def findAll(Pageable pageable) {

        Page<Event> page = eventRepository.findAll(pageable)

        page.content.each {
            it.config.event.size()
            it.config.system.size()
            it.config.subsystem.size()
        }

        return page

    }

}
```

But it is very specific to each query :-(

Comment: I would say it's better to introduce a service layer rather than call repository directly from controller. Transaction is organized on service layer and service returns DTO (not entity). The lazy problem is resolved on service layer and then pure pojo DTO is returned. In you case you may send critical info like DB IDs or password defined on Entity layer.

Comment: Yes you are right. The database keys are skipped with @JsonIgnore. But if a create a Service, how to invoke the Jackson Mapper manually to serialize the result? In my example this is done automatically outside.

Comment: No need to call Jackson Mapper manually. Service returns DTO object using some EntityToDTOConverter. Then you just return the DTO from the controller. Thus service method is marked as Transactional and after the service there is no lazy/entity but pure pojo